# What do you call someone who gives out points?

Tags: single-word-requests

In this case, you'll get a certain amount of points for completing small events. Let's say, for example, you get 10 points if you read a book. There is someone supervising your activities and they are the one rewarding you with points. What would you call this person who awards points? All I can think of is "point giver", but I want something a bit more clear and/or professional. Any answers are appreciated!

Example:

> "Jimmy is the best _____. He gave me 50 points for sending a letter to an old folks' home!"

I tried looking for the correct word on https://www.thesaurus.com/ but couldn't find any. Please let me know if you have something in mind!

Comment: Judge? . . . . .

Comment: Is the person judging/assessing and awarding points or just recording what someone else says they did?

Comment: In certain contexts there are special terms, but _get/give points_ doesn't mean anything outside of sports or schools. If you're an adult, when do you "get points"?

Comment: Perhaps *grader*.

Comment: *Point giver* is perfectly fine.

Comment: You **complete tasks**: doing the shopping, fixing a leaky tap, writing a letter to someone,  are not called events.

Comment: monitor, award tracker

Comment: It depends on the context: teacher, employer, stack-exchange user, facebook algorithm, etc. Without that specific context, you fall back to generic terms such as your suggestion of "point giver".

Answer (score 1):

Adjudicator

Adjudicator is a word that you'll hear used sometimes in quiz shows  for the person who adds up points, and moves the game forward by giving a short summary of who's winning.

ad·ju·di·cate

3rd person present: adjudicates
make a formal judgment or decision about a problem or disputed matter.
"the Committee adjudicates on all betting disputes"
act as a judge in a competition.
"we asked him to adjudicate at the local flower show"

Referee is another word that might work.

Comment: Where's this definition from?

Comment: Oxford Languages

Comment: Google 'adjudicate' to see it.

Comment: Better still,  why not include the link and the name of the source in the answer that way you'll get an upvote (points!) from me.

Comment: it doesn't have a link, it's a Google suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is a kind of appraisal,  `appraiser` might be a good option. It is used in more commercial settings, but I think it conveys the meaning satisfactorily in this case. Its British English counterpart is `valuer` which is definitely out of question here, but there is definite sense of appraisal inherent here and appraiser should go well with the meaning.

Here's a definition of the term Appraiser from [Collins' dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/appraiser)

> An appraiser is someone whose job is to estimate the cost or value of
> something such as property.

Here's the definition of Appraise from [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appraise:)

> to evaluate the worth, significance, or status of
> especially : to give an expert judgment of the value or merit of
> . Example- appraise an actor's career